# Reading encrypted pdf Metadata without decrypting the file

Tags: java, itext

I am using iText to encrypt PDF files:

```
stamp.setEncryption(hardPasswordByte, 
                    hardPasswordByte,
                    PdfWriter.ALLOW_PRINTING, 
                    PdfWriter.ENCRYPTION_AES_128 | PdfWriter.DO_NOT_ENCRYPT_METADATA);
```

Notice I am specifying `PdfWriter.DO_NOT_ENCRYPT_METADATA`.

But when I try only to read the Document Metadata like this (without decrypting the Document):

```
PdfReader ReadInputPDF = new PdfReader(path);
byte Document_MetaData[] = ReadInputPDF.getMetadata();
```

I get "Bad user password" exception.

Is there a way to read the metadate with out decrypting the document?

Comment: The meta data in question are present in the file as a XML section. You don't use a pdf reader but search the file for such XML section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, as mkl said the PdfWriter.DO_NOT_ENCRYPT_METADATA simply sets the MetaData which can be read as a clear text. Using Java i can simply use InputStream and read the file, searching for the metadata.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try providing password to your `PdfReader` constructor :

```
new PdfReader(path, hardPasswordByte);
```

Comment: I dont have the password i only want the MetaDate

Comment: @Michael You provided `hardPasswordByte` as owner password for your `pdfWriter.setEncryption`. Try using it to instantiate the reader. This is just a guess based on what you posted.

Comment: I am well aware i can read the file with its password, but this is exactly what i am testing: reading the metadate without passing the password!

Comment: @Michael Is it constructor, or `.getMetadata` that throws `BadUserPassword` exception in your case ?